# Windows Batch programs

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments

I have to merge a set of ASCII files and I tried to use this batch file, this one creates a new file which combines all file and removes the header from each of the files.

```
@echo off

FOR /F "delims=*" %%i in (header.txt) do @echo %%i
FOR /F "skip=1 delims=*" %%i in (A1.DAT A2.DAT A3.DAT A4.DAT A5.DAT) do @echo %%i
```

this batch files works, but I want to use wildcard like *.dat instead of providing each file names in the batch file. Could someone help me, how to use wildcard instead of typing individual file names?

Answer (score 1):

Try next code snippet:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
FOR /F "delims=" %%i in (header.txt) do @echo %%i
FOR %%I in (*.dat) do @FOR /F "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%i in ("%%~I") do @echo %%i
```

Use it e.g. as follows: `>"1127756merged.txt" 1127756.bat`

Here

- `FOR %%I in (*.dat)` loop returns list of all `.dat` files in current directory folder;

  - this list is *dynamic* i.e. loads even files which you add to the folder during processing;
  - to get a *static* list, use `FOR /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /B *.dat')` instead;
- nested `%%i` loop treats all that files in sequence;
- note `delims=` instead of your `delims=*`; (and think about: maybe I'm wrong with this suggestion).

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (helpful particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~I` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- (`>>`, `>` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)